# Rails: Destroy not working for nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have an application where the user can create a `gallery` to which he/she can attach some pictures. I use carrierwave for this purpose and it's structured as following.
Each `gallery` has many `pictures` and each `picture` has 1 `image`.

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :pictures, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, allow_destroy: true;
end
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :gallery
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

The gallery and pictures are uploaded and edited in the following manner

```
<ul>
    <%= f.fields_for :pictures do |builder| %>
       <li class="clearfix fields">
       <% if p.object.image.length > 1 %>
           <%= image_tag(p.object.image)  %>
       <% end %>
       <%= p.file_field :image %>
       <%= p.text_field :title %>
       <% if p.object.image.length > 1 %>
           <br />
           <%= p.hidden_field :_destroy %>
           <a href="#" class="delete-link">Remove picture</a>
       <% end %>
       </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

When the `delete-link` is clicked, the `_destroy` fields value is set to `true` (with javascript). This works just fine. I also permit the `_destroy` attribute in my strong parameters and I see it being passed to the `GalleriesController`.

```
def gallery_params
    params.require(:gallery).permit(:title, :synopsis, :thumb, pictures_attributes: [:image, :title, :id, :_destroy])
end
```

But somehow the pictures are not being deleted. Any idea what more needs to be added, or what needs to be corrected?

EDIT,
the params that are being passed look like this

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"lTad77QCH7hDcSaKm0EFI90KhY+nVwNS4jRNADC7DSR1ATxszDwlHefWNyNEdVqdqpuvEh9PkBFnoPIfnp9JKw==", "gallery"=>{"title"=>"new one", "synopsis"=>"ssfjalsdj;fk", "pictures_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"title"=>"portfolio", "_destroy"=>"true", "id"=>"4"}, "1"=>{"title"=>""}}, "thumb_cache"=>""}, "commit"=>"Update Gallery", "id"=>"2"}
```

the controllers look like this

```
class GalleriesController < ApplicationController
    def update
        @gallery.update(gallery_params)
        redirect_to(gallery_path(@gallery))
    end
end
class PicturesController < ApplicationController
    def destroy
        @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])  
        @picture.destroy
    end
end
```

Comment: try to remove this `dependent: :destroy` on model Gallery.

I usually using this gem https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon
to make nested form :d

Comment: That doesn't work. `dependent: :destroy` is there to delete the pictures if I delete the gallery

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me... This is a bit of a reach, but have you tried with a '1', instead of 'true'?

Comment: For first look - I think you don't send `:id` to server. Not test it.
And try to use 1 instead of bool(mb it's helps, need to debug)
Can you paste controller code and params sample?

Comment: `:id` is part of `picture_attributes[]` and setting `_destroy` to 1 doesn't solve it saddly enough. I added some more info to my starting post

Comment: Yes, that doesn't work...

Comment: Seriously, I have no idea why it's not destroy nested models. All seems like correct. I tested on my local project all cases and all works fine(but i'm sending array like `[{'id' => '1', destroy=> 'true'}]` in attributes, your implementation must works too.)
It's some kind of mysterious bug. =) Sorry, I think I can't help you with it.
I think problem not in accepts_nested_attributes. Try to debug your controller methods for example.

Answer (score 0):

I would first change a few things:

1) In your gallery model there is an unnecessary `;` after `true`.

2) In your form you are passing `p` in your picture fields instead of `builder`. Either use `builder` in your fields or change `builder` to `p`.

3) In your Gallery Controller did you set @gallery before trying to update it? If not put this code before your call to update @gallery: `@gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])`

The destroy method on your pictures controller is probably not related. I don't think it gets called through this when it's nested in another model.

After you do those things, also try updating something else (not destroy) and see if the changes get saved. This will help narrow down the problem. Also take a look in your console and see if there are any error after the param hash is being passed. Sharing those in your question could help.